# VueJS/Javascript - componentes e variáveis

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Olá! Eu tenho uma restAPI que me retorna um `array` de nomes, eu queria saber como eu faço para te-los como `componentes`. Abaixo dá para entender melhor:

```
import produtos from './produtos'
import artigos from './artigos'

var API_Request = ["produtos", "artigos"]

var router = [ ...API_Request ]

const app = new Vue({
    router
}).$mount('#container')
```

O `API_Request` vem como `string`, como eu faço para converte-lo para componentes que foram importados acima?

Obrigado!

Comment: Essas strings da API_Request são sempre alguns dos modulos que sabes ter certo? ou seja podes ter `import` de x módulos que a API sempre vai referir a eles certo?

Comment: Essas strings da API_Request sempre vem módulos que tenho certeza de que tenho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sugiro criares um objeto para poderes referir chaves com essas strings.

Algo assim:

```
import produtos from './produtos'
import artigos from './artigos'

const componentes = {
    produtos: produtos,
    artigos: artigos
}

var API_Request = ["produtos", "artigos"]

var router = API_Request.map(key => componentes[key])

const app = new Vue({
    router
}).$mount('#container')
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!! Funcionou perfeitamente :) !
Eu sou precisei somar os arrays criando com : var mergeArrays = [].concat.apply([], router);